# H infty optimization of transfer function matrix - which method?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have a two-dimensional (2 x 2) transfer function matrix like this:

[image]

The aim is to solve optimization problem:

[image: $$\min_{x, y} ||G||_\infty $$]

I used the code below, but there is no convergence:

```
s = tf('s');
x = fmincon(@(x) norm([1/(x(1)*s+1), 1/(s+0.5); 3/(s+3), 1/(x(2)*s+2),inf),[1 1],[],[],[],[],[0 0],[2 2])
```

How can I treat this optimization problem? Which one of optimization methods is useful for this problem?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is more of a mathematical problem than a programming problem. Consider posting in [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get an answer here